# plural or single objects following 'the requirements of...”?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I want to know more about the end of this sentence:

> 1. Whether it’s a cow or a goat that’s producing the milk, we can provide a suitable solution that meets the requirements of **the customer, the farmer and the animal**.
> 2. Whether it’s a cow or a goat that’s producing the milk, we can provide a suitable solution that meets the requirements **of customers, farmers and animals**.

Sentence (1) sound weird to me, because there are different customers, farmers and animals, and I would prefer (2). However, I am not sure that much.

Which one should I choose?

Also, why is 'the' is used, because the sentence does not refer to a specific customer, farmer, and animal?

Comment: I'd be interested to see why this is true, from a grammarian's point of view, but 1) is the better version, no doubt. It sounds like 'advertising copy'. 2) sounds like a school essay. [I don't *think* either is strictly 'wrong', btw]

Comment: #1 sounds better to me, because you start off by saying "**a** cow or **a** goat", which implies one animal, hence "the animal" and not "animals".  But I think it's mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: I see no reason to suggest any of the four alternatives here are any "better" or "worse" than any other. It's fine with bare singular ***or*** plural forms, ***with or without*** a preceding definite article ***the***. They're all just equally valid stylistic choices.

Comment: Surely **a cow** and **a goat** in this context are merely representative of their species, as in: **The dog is a loyal friend but it's the horse that one rides**.Equally: *The pen is mightier than the sword*. All of these use the singular to represent the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence 1 is correct because it finishes with a singular subject, matching the singular subject it starts with:

> Whether it’s **a** cow or **a** goat that’s producing the milk, we can provide **a** suitable solution that meets the requirements of **the** customer, **the** farmer and **the** animal.

Because of the use of **a** (and an *or* conjunction) it's only a single cow or goat that's being discussed. Given that, it's far more likely that there's only a single customer or farmer milking that single cow or goat.

It is **the** customer or farmer, because you've already introduced a single animal to the sentence; by extension, there will be a specific customer or farmer associated with that animal.

---

Note that I find the use of *the customer, the farmer* to be strange. They should both be the same person—so I'd expect only one or the other to be mentioned. Or it should be made clear that they aren't separate people: *the customer (a farmer) and the animal.* Or possibly *the customer or farmer and the animal* if there's a possibility that a customer is not a farmer.

---

In order for sentence 2 to work, you'd have to modify the first part to match the plural used in the second part:

> Whether it’s **cows** or **goats** ***that produce*** the milk, we can provide suitable ***solutions*** that ***meet*** the requirements of customers, farmers and animals.